# WC_Order_Query where meta data does not exist or is not equal to

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, orders

I am trying to query all orders from the database where a custom post meta field is not set, or is not equal to 'yes'. It seems I am not able to get it to work properly.

I have this:

```
$query = new \WC_Order_Query([
    'date_completed' => $range,
    'x_days_follow_up_email' => 'yes' // Note: Compares '!='
]);
```

Then I have this hooked into `woocommerce_order_data_store_cpt_get_orders_query`:

```
if (!empty($query_vars['x_days_follow_up_email'])) {
    $query['meta_query'][] = [
            'key' => 'x_days_follow_up_email',
            'value' => esc_attr($query_vars['x_days_follow_up_email']),
            'compare' => '!='
        ]
    ];
}

return $query;
```

This returns nothing. If I change the compare to `==`, it returns the orders with the meta set to 'yes'. So I was thinking I might have to include `NOT EXISTS` somehow, like this:

```
if (!empty($query_vars['x_days_follow_up_email'])) {
    $query['meta_query'][] = [
        'relation' => 'OR',
        [
            'key' => 'x_days_follow_up_email',
            'value' => esc_attr($query_vars['x_days_follow_up_email']),
            'compare' => '!='
        ],
        [
            'key' => 'x_days_follow_up_email',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        ]

    ];
}

return $query;
```

This sadly does not work either. I could write my own WP_Query for this, but there are a lot of orders and I find that the query takes ages. The `$range` in my code is basically all orders that are 11 - 8 days old. And I only want the orders that do not have the meta `x_days_follow_up_email`, or when that meta is set but not to `yes`.

It seems that it should be possible? For what it's worth, this was working before, but it suddenly stopped working after an update for reasons unknown:

```
$query = new \WC_Order_Query([
    'date_completed' => $range,
    'meta_key' => 'x_days_follow_up_email',
    'meta_value' => 'yes',
    'meta_compare' => '!='
]);
```

Seems simple enough, but I can't seem to make it happen.

**UPDATE:**

I have also tried coding this into a normal WP_Query, but it reaches the maximum execution time of the server and seems very inefficient:

```
  $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'shop_order',
        'post_status' => 'wc-completed',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => '_date_completed',
                'value' => array($rangeStart, $rangeEnd),
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                'type' => 'NUMBER'
            ),
            array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key' => 'x_days_follow_up_email',
                    'value' => 'yes',
                    'compare' => '!=',
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'x_days_follow_up_email',
                    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated** - You need some additional code, to handle custom meta data like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_data_store_cpt_get_orders_query', 'order_data_store_custom_query_var', 10, 2 );
function order_data_store_custom_query_var( $query, $query_vars ) {
    if ( ! empty( $query_vars['xdays_fup'] ) ) {
        $query['meta_query'][] = array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array( 
                'key'     => 'x_days_follow_up_email',
                'value'   => esc_attr( $query_vars['xdays_fup'] ),
                'compare' => '!=',
            ),
            array( 
                'key'     => 'x_days_follow_up_email',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            )
        );
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Then you will change your query to:

```
$query = new \WC_Order_Query([
    'date_completed' => $range,
    'xdays_fup' => 'yes'
]);
```

It should work.

Comment: This sadly returns an empty array even though I have three orders with no meta set, and one order with the meta set to yes in the given time range. If I set 'xdays_fup' => 'no', it returns the one order with the meta set to 'yes'. So it seems like it is ignoring the orders where the meta is not set?

Comment: I have updated the post with a WP_Query I have tried, but it times out. Will the correct solution here be to loop all orders and add the meta with value "no"? It seems to me like "!=" should return a post if it does not have the meta added, because it is not equal to the value I am comparing it to if it does not exist. But maybe that is not how the meta query works?

Comment: I didn't see your update before now because I didn't get notified. This new code should work, but it also has the same problems as all the other things I have tried. The query times out before returning any results. I guess this does not create an optimal query. Trying to just get orders by comparing to already existing meta is much, much faster than trying to fetch orders where meta does not exist. Even when specifying a range where there are only 4 existing orders. I am still going to mark this as a correct answer, but it will not work for me performance wise.